# Youtube does not work with cookies enabled on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, firefox, google-chrome, youtube

Youtube has an awkward problem. I can not watch any videos unless I disable cookies for www.youtube.com and it bothers me to do this.
This is probably not a Flash issue since it can be solved by configuring the browser, but I don't know if it is a Linux problem or Youtube's fault.
Does anybody else experience this or do you guys watch Youtube with no problems on Linux?

Comment: Does it work with neither Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Both have the same problem and the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve this by deleting the YouTube cookie for Firefox and Chrome.

- In Firefox, this is done from Edit > Preferences > Privacy > Remove
  Individual Cookies > [search for] "youtube"
- In Chrome or Chromium, This can be done with [image: img] > Settings > Show Advanced Settings > Privacy > Content Settings > Cookies > Cookies and Site Data > [hover mouse over "youtube.com" and click the "X" on the right hand side]

Comment: Deleting them just once does not work. I watch just one video and it stops working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problem with Firefox 25.0.1 with Ubuntu 13.04 with youtube too. But not just you tube, other sites were not working well.

What I did to solve this problem is downloading Firefox 25.0 from [Mozzila Firefox 25.0 AMD 64 Fremch](http://download.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/25.0/linux-x86_64/fr/). Move up and down to select the appropriate version for your language and machine architecture. Do not download version 25.0.1 because I was having problem with this version too.

I don't know if the version 25.0.1 that is causing the problem because the problems I did experience may due to the Ubuntu plugins I did install. These plugins were deactivated when I started Firefox 25.0.

I did not install the Flash plugin. I am using Youtube with HTML 5. [Activate Youtube HTML5](http://www.youtube.com/html5)

Here are the command I used to deactivate Ubuntu Firefox (25.0.1) and replace it by the new version I did install in `/opt` (25.0):

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/firefox /usr/bin/firefox_
sudo mv ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

This well, the graphical shell will start the Firefox version located in /opt.

Comment: I did uninstall the Ubuntu extensions and the Ubuntu Firefox version 25.0.1 is working well again.

Comment: Did install Flash back:

    sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer

It seems the problem was the Ubuntu plugins. Things are working well now.